# New to C++, signature definition

Tags: c++

I have a function written in C++:

```
foo (IN bool someMode = false)
```

What does that mean? 
Will someMode always be initialized to false? Even if foo is called with true?

Answer (score 3):

It means even though `foo` takes one argument, you can call this function without passing any argument as:

```
 foo(); //ok
```

If you call like this, then `someMode` value will be `false`, as that is what its *default* value is.  `someMode = false` in the function signature means, if no argument is passed, then `someMode` will be `false`. In programming, such a parameter is said to be default parameter, and `false` in this context is said to be *default* value for the parameter.

However, if you wish, you can pass argument:

```
foo(false); //ok 
foo(true);  //ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a default parameter, allowing you to omit it, basically, if you call:

```
foo();
```

then someMode will still exist, and be set to false, but if you call

```
foo(true);
```

then someMode will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `IN` is macro that does nothing, and just lets you know that an argument is an input to the function, so what you really have is `foo(bool someMode=false)`.  What you're left with is a default argument. This means you can call the code like this:

```
foo(true); // Here someMode=true
foo(false); // Here someMode=false
```

or like this

```
foo(); // Here someMode=false
```

Comment: Thanks Michael !! appreciate quick response !!